PHP DomCrawler - Scrap Popup window html after form being sent
I'm scraping a web site with forms.
The first page has a form that posts to the second page.
The second page has a form which when submitted it opens a popup window (using JS).
That popup window has a form which when submitted returns to the second page but modified.
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $url);
$form = $crawler->filter('#Form')->form();
$second = $this->client->submit($form);

$form2 = $second->filter('#Form')->form();
$third = $this->client->submit($form2);

The question is how can I get the popup data that appears when I submit the second form?

Popups happen from a client-side (Javascript) call, and will not be available in the initial request. You need to find out what the URL is of the popup window and how it's generated before you can scrape it in a subsequent call with PHP.

Or you have to use a library which behaves as a headless browser and can interact with the system and execute JS. We don't know what crawler tool you're using
